# Best way to return a set of values from a function

Tags: c

I have a list of counters and I am checking each counter at each clock interrupt. Whenever the counters expire I need to return all the counters expired to the calling code so as to know which one expired. What would be the most elegant way to do the same?
 I was thinking about setting each flags in an array and checking. But I found that to be one more round of checking which is done while counter expiry is checked.

The function CheckCounterExpiry is called whenever a clock tick expires. The return is not handled below as that is my query.

```
void  CheckCounterExpiry()
{
Node *prev, *temp;
if (head == NULL)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    /*Check for counter and delete, return set of deleted id types as to signal            which got deleted*/
    prev = NULL;
    temp = head;        
    while (temp->next != NULL) 
    {
        if (clocktick== temp->target)
        {
            if (prev == NULL)
            {
                head = NULL;
            }
            /* I need to return the list of temp->counterId here. how to do it best?*/
            prev->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);

        }
        else
        {
            prev= temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Elegance is C? I didn't know that existed.

Comment: See this (closed) challenge on code golf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15182/update-all-with-o1

Comment: Well I was looking for just an answer. Elegance was a wrong word probably.

Comment: @C0D3R I'm just joking. It's been a long day. :)

Comment: What do you mean by interrupt? Are you working on an embedded microcontroller on a demo board or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Paradigm shift.  Do not shrink link in `CheckCounterExpiry()`.

Since you are using a global value `head` to communicate to your ISR (interrupt service routine `void  CheckCounterExpiry()`) what clocks are presently active, I'd recommend that another field `bool Active` added to the `Node`.  In `CheckCounterExpiry()`, set this to false when clock expires.

Thus `CheckCounterExpiry()` only updates the `Active` field.  Let a another routine, say `Node *GetExpiredClock()` *consume* the de-activated clocks.  It gets *1* expired clock if any, else returning NULL.  It shrinks the list by 1 as *this* is when the `node` is done.  Call multiple times if needed.  This routine may need interrupt protection to insure `CheckCounterExpiry()` is not called.

Further, inside `CheckCounterExpiry()` change as follows.  This prevents a mis-clock tick from mesisng everything up.

```
// if (clocktick== temp->target)
if (clocktick >= temp->target)
```